# how to use two conditions in select conditions in xslt when using Apply template

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="block2sequence" select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][position()=1] and NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$strXSLMsgType][position()=1]"/>
```

why cant i use two conditions in above select condition, can any one suggest me

Comment: THis isn't clear: What do you want to achieve, what do you want selected, which are the two conditions you can't specify (in the above `select` attribute you actually have two conditions specified).

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates mode="block2" select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][position()=1] and NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$PackSEQ][position()=1] "/> since like this we are using in match=" X and y" similarily when i m doin here it was say wrong

Comment: @_pravz: Better edit your question and describe well what the problem is. Your comment is still confusing.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev yeah i have edit the template y it was throwing error can you please suggest

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev i have two use conditions in select because there $PackageId and $PackSEQ in all newdataset/table packageid will be same and packseq WILL VARY SO BY USING TWO CONDITION THEN MY PROBLEM WILL RESOLVE SINCE WHEN I M TRYING TO UPDATE TWO CONDITIONS IN APPLY TEMPLATE SELECT IT WAS THROWIN AN Error, kindly advice me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:apply-templates mode="block2" 
>      select="NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][position()=1] "/>
> ```
>
> why cant i use two conditions in above select condition

I guess this is to mean, "*why can't the two conditions be specified in the same predicate?*"

**The answer is that the expression**:

```
NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId and position() = 1]
```

**isn't equivalent at all to the 1st expression above**.

The first expression selects the first `Table` child of `NewDataSet` such that the string value of its `CTD_CTD_PKG_ID` child is equal to the string value of `$PackageId`. In this case we don't know which child (at which position) of `NewDataSet` will be selected -- any child that happens to be the first with the specified properties, will be selected.

On the other side, the latter expression selects the first `Table` child of `NewDataSet` *only if* the string value of its `CTD_CTD_PKG_ID` child is equal to the string value of `$PackageId`. In this case, if anything is selected, it would be the first `Table` child.

**If you want an equivalent expression to the first one, that has only one predicate**, one such expression is:

```
NewDataSet/Table
      [CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId 
     and 
       not(preceding-sibling::Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId ])
      ]
```

**Update**: The OP has published a code snippet:

> ```
>  <xsl:apply-templates mode="block2sequence" select=
>     "NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][position()=1]
>     and
>      NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$strXSLMsgType][position()=1]"/>
> ```

**This code will cause an error thrown at compile time by the XSLT processor**.

The value of the `select` attribute is a boolean (expr1 and expr2), however templates in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 can only be applied on nodes. A boolean isn't a node -- hence the error.

**Solution**:

**My first guess is** that you want templates to be applied on *both* nodes. If this is so, then use:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="block2sequence" select=
    "NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId][1]
    |
     NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$strXSLMsgType][1]"/>
```

**My second guess is** that you want templates applied only on the first of the two nodes. If this is so, then use:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates mode="block2sequence" select=
    "(NewDataSet/Table[CTD_CTD_PKG_ID =$PackageId]
    |
     NewDataSet/Table[CTD_SEQ_NUM =$strXSLMsgType]
     )
      [1]
"/>
```

**Notes**:

1. Please, learn how to ask a question -- provide all relevant data and explain -- in the question, not in subsequent comments.
2. Did you know that `[1]` is equivalent to `[position()=1]` and is shorter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two conditions and your expression looks perfectly correct. If it is failing with an error, please tell us the error. If it is not selecting what you want, then (a) show us your source document, and (b) tell us what you want to be selected.

(You know, your question gives so little information, you don't give the impression that you really want an answer.)

Comment: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.   -->NewDataSet/Table...] [position()=1]<--  this is the error which was getting for me